# The verb toggle before a gerund

Tags: articles, gerunds

How can I refer to switching a functionality on and off, such as reading tags for songs, by using the verb toggle? Can it be used like the 'stop doing something' construct? I saw a couple of examples for 'toggle between...' and 'toggle through...' in Merriam-Webster dictionary, all of which included non-gerund nounds, and that's straightforward. Also, I'm not sure about using the definite article before the gerund; I know that singular countable nouns must be used with an article except for special cases, such as headings or maybe explicitly terse writings, but is it required in this case?

I considered the below wordings:

- Toggle reading tags
- Toggle the reading of tags
- Toggle tag reading (which sounds awful, not always possible, e.g. 'toggle sorting by time')

Since I've been using the first wording for some time, I have become used to it, but I'm not sure it's a correct usage.

Note that I'd like to use the verb toggle rather than any alternatives, if grammatically possible.

Comment: To toggle is not to shut something off but to switch between two states. A light switch toggles: on to off, off to on.

Comment: I think you want Enable Tag Reading / Disable Tag Reading. See: https://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Media/Music

Comment: @YosefBaskin Edited the question slightly; I meant referring to both on and off with the verb toggle.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I want to refer to only one action to both enable and disable, hence toggle.

Comment: Don't you need to *Toggle between Tag Reading on & off*?

Comment: *Toggle Tag Reading on and off*. cf. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wrong per se. This type of usage hardly follows the rules of normal written and spoken language anyway

For instance, options like

- Toggle Ray Tracing
- Toggle Anti-Aliasing

Are both existing cases that are used widely enough that they're considered normal.

You could also try using Disable, or Enable instead

Comment: Well that's what I'm asking: How do you use toggle with a gerund within the "normal written and spoken language"? If it's not that, it is grammatically wrong, right? Also, ray tracing and anti-aliasing are recognized terms, so they're more like toggling <something>, instead of toggling <doing something>. Which of the three wordings I listed are correct do you think? All three?

Comment: The simplest option would be: Toggle "Tag Reading" on and off [if you are referring to it in spoken or written prose. You can use the quotes to "force" grammaticality]. If you are asking me what the option should be called in the UI, that need not / cannot follow any grammatical structure. "Tag Reading" is again the most intuitive choice

Comment: @dex: You have a gerund: *reading*. *Tag* is an adjective: *tag reading*. No problem. Also, I suspect what is meant is not a person reading tags but a program "reading out" tags. (Of course the person can then read the tags that are read out.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Tag is an adjective, really?

Comment: @Arunkgp Do you see any problem with "Toggle reading tags"? Because preserving the structure of a fully blown action clause would be much more usable, e.g. if the action is showing full paths, would you really say "Toggle full path showing", and it gets less usable for  more detailed actions with objects or subordinate clauses, I think. What do you think?

Comment: @dex: Yes, it's an adjectival (attributive) noun. It functions as an adjective. Like *duck* in *duck soup*. *What kind* of soup? *Duck* soup. *What kind* of reading? *Tag* reading.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct ]: "Adjectival noun is a term that was formerly synonymous with noun adjunct but is now usually used to mean "an adjective used as a noun" (i.e. the opposite process, as in the Irish meaning "Irish people" or the poor meaning "poor people")." So, perhaps it's more prudent to call it noun adjunt than adjectival noun.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  By the way, I'd like to ask you the same thing before I close this as it doesn't seem to atract any more answers anyway. To repeat; Do you see any problem with "Toggle reading tags"? Because preserving the structure of a fully blown action clause would be much more usable, e.g. if the action is showing full paths, would you really say "Toggle full path showing", and it gets less usable for more detailed actions with objects or subordinate clauses, I think. What do you think? and Thanks!

Comment: @dex: I understand your logic, but the occurrence of something like *Toggle Full-path showing* leads me to suspect you are using gerunds where they don't belong. *Tag reading* is an actual thing (at least in some contexts). What is *full-path showing*? More context and an example of the interface you are documenting would be helpful.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "full path showing" is the action of showing full paths in the playlist, so instead of "toggle full paths on and off", "toggle showing full paths" looks like a better option to me. But still unresolved as it is. Alright then, let me mark the only answer as correct. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @dex: Why not just *Toggle Full Path* and *Toggle Tag Reading*? On/off should be obvious enough. I think you should use the name of the toggle—its label. *Full Path* can be on or off. *Tag Reading* can be on or off.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I posted an answer instead of commenting in multiple parts as the site has been warning about avoiding extended discussions in comments already. That should leave a door open for future contributors perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "show" may also be left out in this case, like on and off, since it can be inferred, but that's not something one can count on.

One simply wouldn't always be able to say "stop <something>", instead of saying "stop <doing something>", and that's probably why there is such a construct in the language.

For simpler actions such as turning a fan on, the label may read just "Fan", since on/of can be inferred, or for showing full paths, the label may be read just "Full paths" since showing/not-showing can be inferred, although this isn't the only thing you can do with full paths really. Every action clause, such as "going to school 1 hour earlier", can be toggled (i.e. switched between doing and not doing, or being done and not being done for that matter), and computer programs do too many of those complex actions. Therefore, for an action bound to a key, the functionality of the key is to toggle <doing that action>, and this may very well be the label of the toggle/key.

Therefore, I lean towards Using "toggle <doing> something" instead of "enable/disable <doing> something", as it is less typing and looks better I think. But how grammatically correct it is is the question.

Thanks again.